# Dont use Bootstrap styling for section of page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a page where there is currently more than one form. I used the standard Bootstrap form styling for some of these forms.

The problem is that the Bootstrap CSS gets applied to forms which it is not supposed to.

Is there a way to add a class or `data-*` attribute that will force Bootstrap to not apply to that form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You would have to write a new set of rules to apply to the forms you do not wish to be styled by Bootstrap. For example, give the forms a class name of "someClass" and use the following selector:

```
form.someClass {
    /* Your form styles */
}
```

You can place this in a new stylesheet, and include that stylesheet *after* the Bootstrap stylesheet to override any Bootstap styles you want to.

Comment: I knew there wasnt any but was still taking the chances

Answer (score 2):

[Namespace the hell out of your CSS](http://www.starrhorne.com/2012/02/16/building-front-ends-that-dont-suck-five-tips-for-rails-developers.html), it's an advice I follow for every project and I hadn't done wrong.

Read on Namespaces from the [LESS documentation](http://lesscss.org/#-namespaces) and re-generate the CSS from the LESS file after the proper modifications in the Bootstrap LESS file.

Comment: If you don't have an automatic less to css in your IDE or in your build cycle, you can generate it manually with this desktop app: http://wearekiss.com/simpless